# Hamming SEC/DED extra parity bit

Tags: error-correction, parity, hamming-code

I'm having some troubles with the SEC/DED error correction code. It seems I've found some cases in which the decoder thinks a double bit flip occured but only one really occured. I suppose I did somthing wrong, but I was not able to understand what.
Let me show you an example.

Suppose I want to encode the 4 bits `1011` using a (7,4) code plus an extra bit needed to perform the two-error-detection. The coded word should be `00110011`, where the most significant bit is the extra parity bit, the following two are p0 and p1 and so on.

Now, let's suppose that during a transmission the less significant bit is flipped; thus the received word will be `00110010`. The receiver will extract from this code the four received data bits 1010 and will construct a new code which will result `01011010`. Finally the receiver will perform a bitwise xor of the two codes obtaining `0111`. The last three bits says that bit 7 has been flipped (which is right), but the first bit is 0 and, as far as i know, the decoder should consider this situation as if more than a bit flip has occured.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the problem.

In the example above I calculate the syndrome and then I compute a new overall parity bit of the resultant codeword. Instead, I should check the overall parity of the received word and set the error_happened boolean to that value; then calculate the syndrome.